# Does delete_post_thumbnail() actually delete the image?

Tags: post-thumbnails

When running [delete_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_thumbnail), does it **delete** the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it certainly doesn't. It is simply a case of poor choice of naming. The function should have been named **unset**_post_thumbnail(), particularly when we already have [set_post_thumbnail()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail).

Today's WordPress annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things found odd. And no it does not delete the file neither it remove it from the server. What it actually does is just remove the **meta entry

```
/**
 * Remove metadata matching criteria from a post.
 *
 * You can match based on the key, or key and value. Removing based on key and
 * value, will keep from removing duplicate metadata with the same key. It also
 * allows removing all metadata matching key, if needed.
 *
 * @since 1.5.0
 *
 * @param int    $post_id    Post ID.
 * @param string $meta_key   Metadata name.
 * @param mixed  $meta_value Optional. Metadata value. Must be serializable if
 *                           non-scalar. Default empty.
 * @return bool True on success, false on failure.
 */
function delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value = '' ) {
    // Make sure meta is added to the post, not a revision.
    if ( $the_post = wp_is_post_revision($post_id) )
        $post_id = $the_post;

    return delete_metadata('post', $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);
}
```